# Proving a rule about del operator as applied to matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How can I prove the following easily?(If it is true of course.)

\begin{align}
\nabla_{\mathbf{x}_k} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbf{x}^{T}_i \mathbf{W}_{ij} \mathbf{x}_j   \right)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\mathbf{W}_{kj}\mathbf{x}_{j}+\mathbf{W}_{jk}^{T}\mathbf{x}_j)
\end{align}

Here each $\mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$ is a different vector, and each $\mathbf{W}_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ is a different matrix of real numbers for $i,j = 1,2,...,n$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The del operator](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251486/the-del-operator)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro If you believe they are duplicate, please tell me how can I apply the answer to that question to this one. Then I will know the answer. In that question vectors to the right and left of the matrix are same, in this one they are not.

Comment: Well, the fact is that $$x^TWx$$is just a condensed notation to say $$\sum_{i,j} x_i W_{ij}x_j.$$ That's why I say that those questions are really the same: the difference is only apparent. Don't you agree?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes, but in this case these are vectors and matrices, while in the other question these were real numbers. Can you show me how can I solve this question using the result from the linked question?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro And the answer is also different.. In this question the two matrices in the answer are different, while in the linked question they were same.

Comment: Ok, I see the subtlety now. Sorry. However, I believe that any method which worked for that question will work for the present one, since the algebraic mechanism is exactly the same.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I finally solved, I hope it is correct derivation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved:
\begin{align}
\nabla_{x_k} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} x^{T}_i W_{ij} x_j   \right)
&= \sum_{i=1,i\neq k}^{n}W_{kj}x_j + \sum_{j=1, j\neq k}^{n}(x^T_jW_{jk})^T + x^T_k W_{kk} x_k\\
\text{using the linked question:}\\
&= \sum_{i=1,i\neq k}^{n}\left( W_{ki}x_i + W^T_{ik}x_i \right)+ W_{kk} x_k + W^T_{kk}x_k\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( W_{ki}x_i + W^T_{ik}x_i \right)
\end{align}